# Targeting objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, object, actionscript, this, target

I am wondering how to target specific objects/instances in flash as3. I have 2 objects on the stage, for now we'll call them `obj1` and `obj2` (with instance names). I am trying to have `ob1`'s rotation speed based on `obj2`'s `y` position. I want to place the code inside of `obj1` so I figured if I wanted to target `obj2` from inside `obj1` I'd just use something like `this.rotation = this.obj2.y / 10;` but for some reason the thing just keeps it's rotation still. I used the "Target" button at the top of the native code editor but it still gave me the same `this.obj2`. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when do you call this.rotation = this.obj2.y / 10 ?

Comment: On an _actions_ frame inside of `obj1`, if your asking if I've used an event listener then yes, it started with a `this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotate);` and then there's a function with `this.rotation = this.obj2.y / 10;` inside it along with some flashing color stuff :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two [DisplayObjetcs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) are next to each other on [stage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html), they have a common parent, so a way to "target" obj2 from obj1 would be:

```
this.rotation = this.parent.getChildByName("obj2").y / 10;
```

In other words, unless you set up your own references to other DisplayObjetcs like in Pan's answer, you can reference them through their position in the hierarchal [display list](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html).

Comment: Thanks but when I do this I get an error? _1119:_ _Access_ _of_ _possibly_ _undefined_ _property_ _slider_ _through_ _a_ _reference_ _with_ _static_ _type_ _flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer_. Also obj2 is actually called slider.

Comment: Sorry, I was using AS2 syntax (perhaps fooled by the sample code :), in AS3, you need to use getChildByName(). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update obj1's rotation based on obj2'y, you should call this.rotation = this.obj2.y / 10 in a ENTER_FRAME handler. Or when the obj2's y changes, call the function in obj1 to change rotation.

Assume A is obj1 class

**Solution 1**, use enter_frame event

```
class A {

    private var obj2:Object;

    public function class A($obj2:Object) {
        obj2 = $obj2;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeRotation);
    }


    private function changeRotation(e:Event):void {
        this.rotation = this.obj2.y / 10;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**, change rotation when obj2.y changed

```
class A {

    public function changeRotation(obj2:Object):void {
        this.rotation = this.obj2.y / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have an ENTER_FRAME listener. If I were to use `this.rotation++;` it would turn but at a reasonably slow rate (1 degree 60 times a second). As for the `this.obj2.y` it doesn't target the object so I was wondering if there's a slight alternate to this line only that will enable it to target `obj2` from inside `obj1`.

Comment: Have you change obj2 refrerence? Like obj2 = new type()?  You may trace obj2's y when obj2 moves.